# Octave parse variable to shell script

Tags: shell, parsing, ubuntu, octave

I have shell script that consist of different scripts and I use shell script to connect them all to one automated process. I try to process radar imagery and I need to use Octave for some calculations -> threshold value for classification.

I want to parse calculated result from octave to shell script so I could use it as command input variable to another script. I do not want to write octave outputs to a file, because there will be hundreds of tiles to process. Is there a way I could parse calculated variable from octave script to shell script ?

EDIT: I have changed my long code by simple example based on comment

Basic example:

Make calculation in octave.

```
#!/usr/bin/env octave
# file: octave.m
result= 1 + 2
```

Parse it to the shell script as variable.

```
  #!/bin/sh
  octave octave.m # I want to get one number value 
  # some method to get result from octave script
  ./shell2.sh result
```

Use the variable in another script.

```
   #!/bin/sh
   #file: shell2.sh
   echo result
```

Comment: You should write a [MCVE] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Andy I have changed whole code by basic example

Comment: okay, there are several ways. I would let the octave script to print the result to stdout like other unix utilities would do and read this back in bash. Another (dirty?) way is to use setenv from the Octave script. Another writing to a temporary file and read it back

Comment: why not use GNU Octave to loop over your input files? This would be much faster if speed matters

Comment: @Andy thanks for reply. what dou you mean by GNU Octave ?

Comment: [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), since you've added the "octave" tag I thought you already know that software suite.

Comment: @Andy I think we just do not understand each other. I have Octave and use it to loop over files and process them but I need to use calculated value in different script (different software). That is what I am asking about. I know how to process data in octave, I do not know how to parse value to the shell script to use it in another script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've already told in the comment: let GNU Octave return the value on stdout:

zubro.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
# filename of this script is zubro.sh
result=`octave zubro.m`
./shell2.sh "$result"
```

zubro.m:

```
# filename of this script is zubro.m
x = 1 + 2;
printf ("%i\n", x);
```

shell2.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
# filename of this script is shell2.sh
echo the result is $1
```

when `zubro.sh` called (make sure to `chmod u+x` your scripts...):

```
$ ./zubro.sh 
the result is 3
```